# Is it possible to reuse pointer after free "legally" by "new" repeatedly until the same address returned again?

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior

I know if the object is deleted the address is freed, if write content to that, it is using dangling pointer:

```
delete a;
memmove(a,new A(),sizeof(A));
```

so, I try to reuse pointer "legally"(without undefined behaviour) by creating objects repeatedly until the same address is allocated again:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int* a=new int;
    delete a;
    int* b=new int;
    while(b!=a){
        delete b;
        b=new int;
        *b=123;
    }
    printf("%d\n",*a);
    return 0;
};
```

in the code b should be allocated until same address is obtained and then *a should be 123 finally because it points to b, but I run the code several times the value of *a is still 0, why would be that? is this code undefined behaviour? or it is just because reusing pointer in this way is impossible?

I tried to change delete a; to delete b; in the while loop, but it still prints 0 several times.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do such a thing?

Comment: Not quite sure why you think you can do this, also memory addresses that you get back, even if they are repeated, are not guaranteed to point to the same phyiscal addresses. So what you're doing is non-sensical.

Comment: The first time through the loop, you double-delete `a` which is already undefined behavior.

Comment: If you want to re-use the memory, why delete in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement,

```
while(b!=a)
```

is already Undefined Behavior, since `a` is not a valid pointer. Then there's more UB, and a bit more UB.

Comment: Doesn't it become undefined behavior only if `a` is dereferenced? Otherwise isn't it just a pointer referring to some memory address?

Comment: C++11 §3.7.4.2/4 "The effect of using an invalid pointer value
(including passing it to a deallocation function) is undefined". With modern computer operating systems you can't expect very much bad to come from a simple comparison, but in principle it's possible for such a comparison to be implemented by loading a segment selector register and an offset register with the pointer value, where a hardware trap is invoked. For example.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the code that make assignment `*b = 123` is actually executed? It's kind of likely that `b==a` before enter `while` loop and you just don't assign `*b`. Try like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(){
    int* a=new int;
    delete a;
    int* b=new int;
    while(b!=a){
        delete b;
        b=new int;
    }
    *b = 123;
    printf("%d\n",*a);
    return 0; 
}
```

I don't see why the code is illegal, because you can get pointers from where you want, like you can read them from `stdin` or get from network or generate address randomly and until they point to valid address you can use them.

P.S. I read `Cheers and hth. - Alf` answer and the comment under it and read some explanations about what exactly means "using invalid pointer value" and it is UB. So I mistake above. Good news are that it is legal to use incremented once pointer from valid address, so writing loops like `for (iter = begin; iter < end; ++iter) {...}` are not UB, even if `end` doesn't point to address that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not legal. The fact that you can obtain a new, legal, pointer by repeated allocation is as irrelevant as the fact that immediately after free, the page of memory is still owned by the process.

Answer (score 0):

Besides, there are 2 other problems, resulting from typos, I guess:

- Multiple de-allocations of a.
- Memory leak: memory is allocated over and over for b in the loop, but b is never de-allocated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get `*a = 0` printed because you double delete `a`. But if you correct that I think your program does make some sense

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(){
    int* a=new int;
    delete a;
    int* b=new int;
    while(b!=a){
        delete b;
        b=new int;
        *b=123;
    }
    printf("%d\n",*a);
    return 0; 
}
```

Here's how I understand it

1. You `new` and `delete` `a`. After deletion, `a` will be a dangling pointer which will refer to some memory address (say `0xff00`). Since you've already deleted the object (`int`) at that address, it is free to be used for subsequent allocations.
2. Then, you `new` and `delete` `b` until another object (`int`) is allocated at `0xff00`. Now, since variable `a` still has the same address you go out of the loop and print whatever at that address.

Is that what you are trying to do? I don't see anything illegal there (there's nothing wrong with using a deleted pointer, only dereferencing it is illegal which you don't)